# update android-query maven library dependency

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-query

Currently the latest version provided in google code is 0.26.7

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

But the jar in maven repository is still in 0.25.9, which is more than a year ago.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.android-query/android-query

Is there anyway for public to update the library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use an excellent [jitpack](https://jitpack.io) feature. For AQuery please see the following:
https://jitpack.io/#androidquery/androidquery/0.26.9

Comment: Cool, I no longer need this, but it will definitely helps others.